# Remove coinbase tip button from tumblr home page

Tags: blogs, tumblr, coinbase-api

I included a coinbase tip button in post page as HTML. I have to display that button only in the inner page (post page) and not in homepage.

**HTML**

```
<div class="cb-tip-button" data-content-location="" data-href="//www.coinbase.com/tip_buttons/show_tip" data-to-user-id="54c4b9826dbda102f00000a4"></div> 

<script>!function(d,s,id) {var js,cjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],e=d.getElementById(id);if(e){return;}js=d.cr‌​eateElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="coinbase.com/assets/…;}(document, 'script', 'coinbase-tips');</script>
```

How can i remove it?

I can't hide it via CSS. Because the `div` style is loading from their website.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please provide the relevant HTML / CSS and an example to the site displaying the issue.

Comment: <div class="cb-tip-button" data-content-location="" data-href="//www.coinbase.com/tip_buttons/show_tip" data-to-user-id="54c4b9826dbda102f00000a4"></div>
<script>!function(d,s,id) {var js,cjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],e=d.getElementById(id);if(e){return;}js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://www.coinbase.com/assets/tips.js";cjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,cjs);}(document, 'script', 'coinbase-tips');</script>

This is the HTML code i am using along with the post text. The code will display tip button.I want to remove or hide this button in index page.

Answer (score 0):

If its just for the page (permalink page), wrap it in the relevant code:

```
{block:PermalinkPage}

<div class="cb-tip-button" data-content-location="" data-href="//www.coinbase.com/tip_buttons/show_tip" data-to-user-id="54c4b9826dbda102f00000a4"></div> 

<script>!function(d,s,id) {var js,cjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],e=d.getElementById(id);if(e){return;}js=d.cr‌​eateElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="coinbase.com/assets/…;}(document, 'script', 'coinbase-tips');</script>

{/block:PermalinkPage}
```

Again, a live example of the issue would really help clarify the question.